# Any way to make this code smaller/faster?... And is this safe to run?

Tags: batch-file

It's pretty much a code to make about 308 million folders.

```
for %%a in (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K , L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z) do (
md %%a
PUSHD %%a
for %%b in (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K , L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z) do (
    md %%b
    PUSHD %%b
    for %%c in (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K , L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z) do (
        md %%c
        PUSHD %%c
        for %%d in (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K , L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z) do (
            md %%d
            PUSHD %%d
            for %%e in (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K , L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z) do (
                md %%e
                PUSHD %%e
                for %%f in (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K , L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z) do (
                    md %%f
                )
                POPD
            )
            POPD
        )
        POPD
    )
    POPD
)
POPD
)
```

But anyways, I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this/faster processing. Anyone have any clue?

Also... Is this even safe to run?

Comment: The need to create 308 million folders comes up so infrequently for me that I haven't bothered optimizing it.

Comment: Yeah... I also just realized that this would literally take my computer over 3 days to make.

Comment: `is the even safe to run`... sarcasm aside, why do you need to run this

Comment: Every folder requires an entry in the FAT table.  Creating 308M folders is not without its cost.  I can't image how you'd use this.  But is it possible to do a lot more efficiently (see my answer).

Comment: I really don't need to run this. But... 6 levels of folderception... I was just curious how to do it. I think I'm gonna stick with 4 levels. (Doing this on a school computer for a 'password' even though its insanely easy to get around. It's just fun to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really want to create that many directories, so I simplified your example to just make a few and it works just fine.  I ran it from a subfolder, so that's why the tree below looks the way it does.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (A, B, C) do (
  for %%b in (A, B, C) do (
    for %%c in (A, B, C) do (
       md %%a\%%b\%%c
    )
  )
)
```

You don't need the `pushd` or `popd` commands.  Nor do you need to create the folders in each level of the `for` loops.  You simply need to create them all with a single `md %%a\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e\%%f` command in the inner most loop.

Here's the `tree`:

```
C:.
├───A
│   ├───A
│   │   ├───A
│   │   ├───B
│   │   └───C
│   ├───B
│   │   ├───A
│   │   ├───B
│   │   └───C
│   └───C
│       ├───A
│       ├───B
│       └───C
├───B
│   ├───A
│   │   ├───A
│   │   ├───B
│   │   └───C
│   ├───B
│   │   ├───A
│   │   ├───B
│   │   └───C
│   └───C
│       ├───A
│       ├───B
│       └───C
└───C
    ├───A
    │   ├───A
    │   ├───B
    │   └───C
    ├───B
    │   ├───A
    │   ├───B
    │   └───C
    └───C
        ├───A
        ├───B
        └───C
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to batch files and coding in general. That's the exact kind of thing I was looking for, wasn't sure if a command like that existed!